# Can "list_display" show users input on django admin page?

Tags: python, html, django, sqlite

I need to see user's input display on django's admin page, from what i have read, I need to use list_display but there is nothing appearing on admin page. Maybe there is a problem in the views.py but everything looks good.
Here is my code:

Views.py

```
    def process_e(request):

website_name = request.POST["website_name"]
product_name = request.POST["product_name"]
phone_number = request.POST["phone_number"]
website_details = request.POST["website_details"]
website_content = request.POST["website_content"]
created_objs = Enterprise.objects.create(website_name=website_name, product_name=product_name, phone_number=phone_number, website_details=website_details, website_content=website_content)
legth_of_todos = Enterprise.objects.all().count()
created_items = Enterprise.objects.all()

if request.method == 'POST':
    if request.POST.get('website_name') and request.POST.get('product_name') and request.POST.get('phone_number') and request.POST.get('website_details') and request.POST.get('website_content'):
        post=Enterprise()
        post.title= request.POST.get('website_name')
        post.content= request.POST.get('product_name')
        post.content= request.POST.get('phone_number')
        post.content= request.POST.get('website_details')
        post.content= request.POST.get('website_content')
        post.save()
        return render(request, 'enterprise.html', {"created_items":created_items})
    else:
        pass  
else:
        return render(request,'enterprise.html')
```

Admin.py

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from service.models import Enterprise

    class PaymentsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        list_display = ('website_name', 'product_name', 'phone_number', 'website_details', 
    'website_content')

    admin.site.register(Enterprise, PaymentsAdmin)
```

Models.py

```
    from django.db import models

    class Enterprise(models.Model):
        website_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        product_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        website_details = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        website_content = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Html

```
   <div class="form-group">
        <label>Website name</label>
        <input type="text" name="website_name" class="form-control" placeholder="First name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Product name (if there is)</label>
        <input type="text" name="product_name" class="form-control" placeholder="First name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Phone number</label>
        <input type="text" claa="phone_name" class="form-control" placeholder="First name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">What kind of content should your website upload?</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="website_content" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Website details</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="website_details" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. list_display is used to show a model's fields in the ListView of a model. You also need at least one model instance.

Comment: Hey thank you! What do you mean with model instance?

Comment: In this situation, creating an Enterprise item.

Comment: I created an item can you please check  the views.py file, its still not working. In the html i also added {{ created_item.variable_name }} inside a for loop.

Comment: list_display works only for the /admin/ panel if you use the default .html they provide.